# Objective-C: Address sent by the caller different than what is received by the callee?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

For some reason, I'm having this issue randomly pop up where a method that's being called receives a bad address and causes the app to crash. Sure, that's not uncommon, but when I check the frame above the crashing method, the address of the object that I'm passing in is completely different than the address of the argument in the called method.

Comment: We need more info than this, and preferably some code. But it's possible the problem may not be quite what you think. If you are doing something that trashes the stack frame from within the called method -- a bit of dodgy pointer arithmetic or something -- then the apparent values of arguments and local variables after the crash may not be what they were going in.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not doing anything dodgy beyond using basic property getters within the method, but I am doing a lot of multi-threaded processing in parallel. So rather than the called method trashing the stack frame, I guess another thread might be changing the addresses in the above frame so that the values that I see would be different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the property that you're accessing atomic-- also verify and make sure that there isn't another property that overlaps the name within a superclass of the object you're manipulating.